# Can you have different item-text and item-values when using ObjectDataProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

When setting the source of an items control (ComboBox, for example), is it possible to have the SelectedValue property be different than the text that is displayed. I have a ComboBox that I want to display only the time portion of a DateTime, and have the value of each item be the DateTime object itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combobox has an ItemStringFormat property that dictates how items are displayed in the dropdown and textbox parts of the control.

In the case of [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemstringformat.aspx) from the MSDN the SelectedValue will be a datetime objects, while the control itself will display the formatted strings.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97x6twsz.aspx) for how to create the format string that will work for your problem. (Something like "HH:mm:ss" I'd guess)

Comment: Rawk! Thanks a bunch! ("t" works, I believe, for just getting the time).